# Place the contents of a div at the center

Tags: css, html

I have two select boxes and a button panel in between to move the options to and fro.
Right now it looks like the first image below, I want to place the buttons vertically aligned at center with the list boxes like the second image below

[image]

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/johnbk/Fq93w/)

Any help/pointers would be great.

Comment: Will the selects have fixed or dynamic height?

Comment: @Andre - height is dynamic, in my case the size is set via java script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css tables. At first, you need this scaffolding:

```
.table { display: table; }
.row { display: table-row; }
.cell { display: table-cell; }

[...]

<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Lorem [...]</div>
        [...]
    </div>
</div>
```

Next, the cell's vertical arrangement is determined by vertical-align: top|bottom|middle|baseline. Under the hood: Cells that have a lower height than its row, receive a top or bottom padding automatically. With that, a cell and a row are equal to one.

Look at your code that is updated: http://jsfiddle.net/Fq93w/21/. And here is the workaround for IE <= 7:

```
#rightListDiv, #controlPanel, #LeftListDiv {
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! was just looking to do it with CSS alone and this is what I was looking for...time to read upon css tables for me :)...but I can just use your solution as of now, it looks great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Add `margin-top` with value as per your needs, see updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fq93w/11/

Comment: With that approach If I increase my list size I would have to change the margin as well to align the buttons, can we do it in a more generic way without hard coding the margin?

Comment: @johnbk: I cant think of any other solution other than using JavaScript. In that case, height of select box will be found out and based on that, you will have to set margin-top property.

Comment: margin: 0 auto; but i prefer @kay-o-pele solution

Answer (score 0):

Probably wrapping evrything inside one div and giving margin-top in % for controlPanel div, may work for you.

Comment: Again that would be a problem when my list size is dynamically set, I would have to readjust the margin-top and set it via javascript

Comment: @johnbk then using javascript would be efficient way as sarfraz said.